# Послать mp3 файл на скачку браузеру

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, помогите, пожалуйста, решить проблему: имеются mp3 файлы, которые подаются на скачку с помощью `header('Location: '.$mp3url);` Во всех браузерах нормально, но вот в Chrome файл не подаётся на скачку, а открывается для проигрывания в самом браузере, изменил способ отправки на этот

```
header("Content-Type: audio/mpeg, audio/x-mpeg, audio/x-mpeg-3, audio/mpeg3, audio/mp3");
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$mp3name);
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($mp3url));
readfile($mp3url);
```

Так всё нормально подаётся на скачку и в Chrome, но здесь другая проблема: некоторые mp3 файлы не проигрываются, по крайней мере, в Windows XP причина - не в компе, пробовал и на другом точно также.

Comment: Сравните скачанный файл таким способом и снятый с ФТП.

Comment: Сравнивал размер одинаковый только вот в свойтвах файла разница удаляется значение Исполнитель, Альбом, Комментарий ....

Answer (score 2):

Обычно вот такого кода бывает достаточно :

```
$f = 'filename';//только имя файла, если указано расширение, то в 4-й строчке будет так : filename=$f
$df = 'filepath';//адрес файла mp3
header('Content-Type: audio/mpeg');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$f.mp3");
echo file_get_contents($df);
exit;
```

Посмотрите пожалуйста код :

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);
function file_download($filename, $mimetype='audio/mpeg') {
    $download_speed =   51200; // 51200
    $time_discret   =   1;
    if (file_exists($filename)) {
        $f              =   fopen($filename, 'r');
        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'])) {
            $load_from      =   preg_replace('#[^0-9]#', '', $_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE']);
            fseek($f, $load_from);
            $filesize       =   filesize($filename);
            header('HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content');
            header('Content-Type: ' . $mimetype);
            header('Content-Range: bytes '.$load_from.'-'.$filesize.'/'.$filesize);
            header('Last-Modified: ' . gmdate('r', filemtime($filename)));
            header('ETag: ' . sprintf('%x-%x-%x', fileinode($filename), filesize($filename), filemtime($filename)));
            header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
            header('Content-Length: ' . (filesize($filename)));
            header('Connection: close');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($filename) . '";');
        } else {
            header($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"] . ' 200 OK');
            header('Content-Type: ' . $mimetype);
            header('Last-Modified: ' . gmdate('r', filemtime($filename)));
            header('ETag: ' . sprintf('%x-%x-%x', fileinode($filename), filesize($filename), filemtime($filename)));
            header('Content-Length: ' . (filesize($filename)));
            header('Connection: close');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($filename) . '";');
        }
            if((int) $download_speed > 0) {
                while(!feof($f)) {
                    $time_start = microtime(true);
                    echo fread($f, ceil($download_speed*$time_discret));
                    flush();
                    $time_end = microtime(true);
                    $time = $time_end - $time_start;
                    if($time_discret-$time > 0) usleep(($time_discret-$time)*1000000);
                }
            } else {
                while(!feof($f)) {
                    echo fread($f, 1024);
                    flush();
                }
            }
        fclose($f);

    } else {
        header($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"] . ' 404 Not Found');
        header('Status: 404 Not Found');
    }
    exit;
}
#
file_download('./20_dt8_project.mp3', $mimetype='audio/mpeg');
?>
```

У меня сейчас нету времени вам помочь, к сожалению. Код отдаёт файл на указанной скорости и поддерживает докачку.

Comment: Большое спасибо Андрей Аршинов. Всё работает, но при этом способе в браузере не указано время окончания загрузки, размер файла, сколько загружено. Посылаю `Content-Length`, но не действует, а это можно как-то решить?

Comment: Возможно, вы допустили ошибку, попробуйте:

    header('Content-Length: ' . (filesize($df)));

Comment: Нет, всё правильно, ошибки нету, точно так же.

Comment: Получилось что нибудь?

Comment: Нет не получилось Андрей эта функция file_download тоже не помогла не знаю даже в чём проблема вроле Content-Length должен помочь но не получается

Comment: Кстати, в разных браузерах пробовали, или только в одном?

Comment: Пробовар в opera и chrome можете и сами посмотреть mp3axtar.com